# PyYAML getting line number of a node

Tags: python, pyyaml

Is there any way to configure PyYAML so that I can get the line number associated with a given node? When procesing an input file, for example a configuration file, and I encounter a semantic error I would like to report what line number it is on.

I don't see anything immediately obvious in the docs, but there is this `Mark` thing which seems to relate to line numbers.

Comment: I was looking for the same thing and found this [other answer here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319067/parsing-yaml-return-with-line-number).

Answer (score 1):

The extensions I made in [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) include an option to access line and column for collections (YAML: mapping, sequence, set, odict/Python dict, list, set, ordereddict):

```
import ruamel.yaml

data = ruamel.yaml.load("""
# example
- a
- e
- {x: 3}
- c
""", Loader=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripLoader)
assert data[2].lc.line == 3
assert data[2].lc.col == 2
```

both the line and column start counting at 0.

You are right about the Mark "thing", but the standard PyYAML loaders discard it when constructing the Python object. `ruamel.yaml.RoundTripLoader` attaches the line and column information from the start Mark to its collection type (as it does with comments and block/flowstyle info.