# Parsing YAML, get line numbers even in ordered maps

Tags: python, python-3.x, ruamel.yaml, ordered-map

I need to get the line numbers of certain keys of a YAML file.

Please note, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319067/parsing-yaml-return-with-line-number) does not solve the issue: I do use [ruamel.yaml](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml), and the answers do not work with ordered maps.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from ruamel import yaml

data = yaml.round_trip_load("""
key1: !!omap
  - key2: item2
  - key3: item3
  - key4: !!omap
    - key5: item5
    - key6: item6
""")

print(data)
```

As a result I get this:

```
CommentedMap([('key1', CommentedOrderedMap([('key2', 'item2'), ('key3', 'item3'), ('key4', CommentedOrderedMap([('key5', 'item5'), ('key6', 'item6')]))]))])
```

what does not allow to access to the line numbers, except for the `!!omap` keys:

```
print(data['key1'].lc.line)  # output: 1
print(data['key1']['key4'].lc.line)  # output: 4
```

but:

```
print(data['key1']['key2'].lc.line)  # output: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'lc'
```

Indeed, `data['key1']['key2]` is a `str`.

I've found a workaround:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from ruamel import yaml

DATA = yaml.round_trip_load("""
key1: !!omap
  - key2: item2
  - key3: item3
  - key4: !!omap
    - key5: item5
    - key6: item6
""")


def get_line_nb(data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        offset = data.lc.line
        for i, key in enumerate(data):
            if isinstance(data[key], dict):
                get_line_nb(data[key])
            else:
                print('{}|{} found in line {}\n'
                      .format(key, data[key], offset + i + 1))


get_line_nb(DATA)
```

output:

```
key2|item2 found in line 2

key3|item3 found in line 3

key5|item5 found in line 5

key6|item6 found in line 6
```

but this looks a little bit "dirty". Is there a more proper way of doing it?

EDIT: this workaround is not only dirty, but only works for simple cases like the one above, and will give wrong results as soon as there are nested lists in the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is not that you are using `!omap` and that it doesn't give you the line-numbers as with "normal" mappings. That should be clear from the fact that you get 4 from doing `print(data['key1']['key4'].lc.line)` (where `key4` is a key in the outer `!omap`).

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29720789/1307905) answers indicates,

> you can access the property lc on collection items

The value for `data['key1']['key4']` is a collection item (another `!omap`), but the value for `data['key1']['key2']` is not a collection item but a, built-in, python string, which has no slot to store the `lc` attribute.

To get an `.lc` attribute on a non-collection like a string you have to subclass the `RoundTripConstructor`, to use something like the classes in `scalarstring.py` (with `__slots__` adjusted to accept the `lc` attribute and then transfer the line information available in the nodes to that attribute and then set the line, column information:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """
key1: !!omap
  - key2: item2
  - key3: item3
  - key4: !!omap
    - key5: 'item5'
    - key6: |
        item6
"""

class Str(ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.ScalarString):
    __slots__ = ('lc')

    style = ""

    def __new__(cls, value):
        return ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.ScalarString.__new__(cls, value)

class MyPreservedScalarString(ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.PreservedScalarString):
    __slots__ = ('lc')

class MyDoubleQuotedScalarString(ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString):
    __slots__ = ('lc')

class MySingleQuotedScalarString(ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.SingleQuotedScalarString):
    __slots__ = ('lc')

class MyConstructor(ruamel.yaml.constructor.RoundTripConstructor):
    def construct_scalar(self, node):
        # type: (Any) -> Any
        if not isinstance(node, ruamel.yaml.nodes.ScalarNode):
            raise ruamel.yaml.constructor.ConstructorError(
                None, None,
                "expected a scalar node, but found %s" % node.id,
                node.start_mark)

        if node.style == '|' and isinstance(node.value, ruamel.yaml.compat.text_type):
            ret_val = MyPreservedScalarString(node.value)
        elif bool(self._preserve_quotes) and isinstance(node.value, ruamel.yaml.compat.text_type):
            if node.style == "'":
                ret_val = MySingleQuotedScalarString(node.value)
            elif node.style == '"':
                ret_val = MyDoubleQuotedScalarString(node.value)
            else:
                ret_val = Str(node.value)
        else:
            ret_val = Str(node.value)
        ret_val.lc = ruamel.yaml.comments.LineCol()
        ret_val.lc.line = node.start_mark.line
        ret_val.lc.col = node.start_mark.column
        return ret_val


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.Constructor = MyConstructor

data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print(data['key1']['key4'].lc.line)
print(data['key1']['key2'].lc.line)
print(data['key1']['key4']['key6'].lc.line)
```

Please note that the output of the last call to `print` is 6, as the literal scalar string starts with the `|`.

If you also want to dump `data`, you'll need to make a `Representer` aware of those `My....` types.

Comment: OK, so, it looks really complicated and maybe I will stick to my workaround. Thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer for getting the line numbers, I'll leave the dumping (if necessary) to you, as well as doing numbers, bools and other scalars.

Comment: Excellent! This is far better than my workaround, what did not work correctly as soon as there are others nested lists in the way.

Comment: @Anthon can you guide towards documentation about how integers and reals might be handled similarly?

Comment: @NolanConaway There is no such documentation, this is relying much on internals. I often insert print statements in the ruamel.yaml source and rerun a test program until I see where I still have information, where it gets lost and look at how to preserve it (by attaching it to information, like nodes, created at the moment things are lost. Don't forget that although I am very familiar with the code by now, my guess is that I did not even write half of it, the rest coming straight from PyYAML five years ago.

Comment: @Anthon , Good to know, thanks for all you've done on this!

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the @Anthon solution based on ruamel.yaml version 0.17.17, handling scalar, int and bool positions.

```
class MyLiteralScalarString(ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.LiteralScalarString):
    __slots__ = ('comment', 'lc')


class MyFoldedScalarString(ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.FoldedScalarString):
    __slots__ = ('fold_pos', 'comment', 'lc')


class MyDoubleQuotedScalarString(ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString):
    __slots__ = ('lc')


class MySingleQuotedScalarString(ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.SingleQuotedScalarString):
    __slots__ = ('lc')


class MyPlainScalarString(ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.PlainScalarString):
    __slots__ = ('lc')


class MyScalarInt(ruamel.yaml.scalarint.ScalarInt):
    lc = None


class MyScalarBoolean(ruamel.yaml.scalarbool.ScalarBoolean):
    lc = None


class MyConstructor(ruamel.yaml.constructor.RoundTripConstructor):

    def __init__(self, preserve_quotes=None, loader=None):
        super(MyConstructor, self).__init__(preserve_quotes=preserve_quotes, loader=loader)
        if not hasattr(self.loader, 'comment_handling'):
            self.loader.comment_handling = None

    def construct_scalar(self, node):
        # type: (Any) -> Any
        if not isinstance(node, ScalarNode):
            raise ConstructorError(None, None, _F('expected a scalar node, but found {node_id!s}', node_id=node.id),
                                   node.start_mark,)
        ret_val = None
        if node.style == '|' and isinstance(node.value, str):
            lss = MyLiteralScalarString(node.value, anchor=node.anchor)
            if self.loader and self.loader.comment_handling is None:
                if node.comment and node.comment[1]:
                    lss.comment = node.comment[1][0]  # type: ignore
            else:
                # NEWCMNT
                if node.comment is not None and node.comment[1]:
                    # nprintf('>>>>nc1', node.comment)
                    # EOL comment after |
                    lss.comment = self.comment(node.comment[1][0])  # type: ignore
            ret_val = lss
        elif node.style == '>' and isinstance(node.value, str):
            fold_positions = []  # type: List[int]
            idx = -1
            while True:
                idx = node.value.find('\a', idx + 1)
                if idx < 0:
                    break
                fold_positions.append(idx - len(fold_positions))
            fss = MyFoldedScalarString(node.value.replace('\a', ''), anchor=node.anchor)
            if self.loader and self.loader.comment_handling is None:
                if node.comment and node.comment[1]:
                    fss.comment = node.comment[1][0]  # type: ignore
            else:
                # NEWCMNT
                if node.comment is not None and node.comment[1]:
                    # nprintf('>>>>nc2', node.comment)
                    # EOL comment after >
                    fss.comment = self.comment(node.comment[1][0])  # type: ignore
            if fold_positions:
                fss.fold_pos = fold_positions  # type: ignore
            ret_val = fss
        elif bool(self._preserve_quotes) and isinstance(node.value, str):
            if node.style == "'":
                ret_val = MySingleQuotedScalarString(node.value, anchor=node.anchor)
            if node.style == '"':
                ret_val = MyDoubleQuotedScalarString(node.value, anchor=node.anchor)
        if not ret_val:
            if node.anchor:
                ret_val = MyPlainScalarString(node.value, anchor=node.anchor)
            else:
                ret_val = MyPlainScalarString(node.value)
        ret_val.lc = ruamel.yaml.comments.LineCol()
        ret_val.lc.line = node.start_mark.line
        ret_val.lc.col = node.start_mark.column
        return ret_val

    def construct_yaml_int(self, node):
        # type: (Any) -> Any
        width = None  # type: Any
        value_su = self.construct_scalar(node)
        try:
            sx = value_su.rstrip('_')
            underscore = [len(sx) - sx.rindex('_') - 1, False, False]  # type: Any
        except ValueError:
            underscore = None
        except IndexError:
            underscore = None
        value_s = value_su.replace('_', "")
        sign = +1
        # Assuming that I have only "normal" positive int in my case
        """
        if value_s[0] == '-':
            sign = -1
        if value_s[0] in '+-':
            value_s = value_s[1:]
        if value_s == '0':
            ret_val = 0
        elif value_s.startswith('0b'):
            if self.resolver.processing_version > (1, 1) and value_s[2] == '0':
                width = len(value_s[2:])
            if underscore is not None:
                underscore[1] = value_su[2] == '_'
                underscore[2] = len(value_su[2:]) > 1 and value_su[-1] == '_'
            ret_val = BinaryInt(sign * int(value_s[2:], 2), width=width, underscore=underscore, anchor=node.anchor)
        elif value_s.startswith('0x'):
            # default to lower-case if no a-fA-F in string
            if self.resolver.processing_version > (1, 1) and value_s[2] == '0':
                width = len(value_s[2:])
            hex_fun = HexInt  # type: Any
            for ch in value_s[2:]:
                if ch in 'ABCDEF':  # first non-digit is capital
                    hex_fun = HexCapsInt
                    break
                if ch in 'abcdef':
                    break
            if underscore is not None:
                underscore[1] = value_su[2] == '_'
                underscore[2] = len(value_su[2:]) > 1 and value_su[-1] == '_'
            return hex_fun(
                sign * int(value_s[2:], 16),
                width=width,
                underscore=underscore,
                anchor=node.anchor,
            )
        elif value_s.startswith('0o'):
            if self.resolver.processing_version > (1, 1) and value_s[2] == '0':
                width = len(value_s[2:])
            if underscore is not None:
                underscore[1] = value_su[2] == '_'
                underscore[2] = len(value_su[2:]) > 1 and value_su[-1] == '_'
            return OctalInt(
                sign * int(value_s[2:], 8),
                width=width,
                underscore=underscore,
                anchor=node.anchor,
            )
        elif self.resolver.processing_version != (1, 2) and value_s[0] == '0':
            return sign * int(value_s, 8)
        elif self.resolver.processing_version != (1, 2) and ':' in value_s:
            digits = [int(part) for part in value_s.split(':')]
            digits.reverse()
            base = 1
            value = 0
            for digit in digits:
                value += digit * base
                base *= 60
            return sign * value
        elif self.resolver.processing_version > (1, 1) and value_s[0] == '0':
            # not an octal, an integer with leading zero(s)
            if underscore is not None:
                # cannot have a leading underscore
                underscore[2] = len(value_su) > 1 and value_su[-1] == '_'
            return ScalarInt(sign * int(value_s), width=len(value_s), underscore=underscore)
        elif underscore:
            # cannot have a leading underscore
            underscore[2] = len(value_su) > 1 and value_su[-1] == '_'
            return ScalarInt(
                sign * int(value_s), width=None, underscore=underscore, anchor=node.anchor
            )
        elif node.anchor:
            return ScalarInt(sign * int(value_s), width=None, anchor=node.anchor)
        else:
        """
        ret_val = MyScalarInt(sign * int(value_s))
        ret_val.lc = ruamel.yaml.comments.LineCol()
        ret_val.lc.line = node.start_mark.line
        ret_val.lc.col = node.start_mark.column
        return ret_val

    def construct_yaml_bool(self, node):
        # type: (Any) -> Any
        b = super(MyConstructor, self).construct_yaml_bool(node)
        if node.anchor:
            ret_val = MyScalarBoolean(b, anchor=node.anchor)
        else:
            ret_val = MyScalarBoolean(b)
        ret_val.lc = ruamel.yaml.comments.LineCol()
        ret_val.lc.line = node.start_mark.line
        ret_val.lc.col = node.start_mark.column
        return ret_val


MyConstructor.add_constructor('tag:yaml.org,2002:int', MyConstructor.construct_yaml_int)
MyConstructor.add_constructor('tag:yaml.org,2002:bool', MyConstructor.construct_yaml_bool)
```