# Parsing YAML and return with line number

Tags: parsing, go, yaml

I'm creating a document generator from YAML input in Go. It needs to specify which line of the YAML file each item/node is generated from. Is there a way to achieve it in Go?

For example here's a YAML file

```
- key1: item 1
  key2: item 2
- key1: another item 1
  key2: another item 2
```

and I'd like to see the following

```
[
     {'__line__': 1, 'key1': 'item 1', 'key2': 'item 2'},
     {'__line__': 3, 'key1': 'another item 1', 'key2': 'another item 2'},
]
```

I see a similar question answered for Python [Parsing YAML, return with line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319067/parsing-yaml-return-with-line-number) but I'm missing how to make use of https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v3

Answer (score 2):

In Go this is possible by implementing a custom [`Unmarshaler`](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v3#Unmarshaler) and setting the line number manually.

So let's build the data structure we need for the file:

```golang
type ListItem struct {
    Line int

    ListItemData
}

type ListItemData struct {
    Key1 string `yaml:"key1"`
    Key2 string `yaml:"key2"`
}
```

Now we implement the Unmarshaler interface by creating a method on the `ListItem` type:

```golang
func (li *ListItem) UnmarshalYAML(value *yaml.Node) error {
    err := value.Decode(&li.ListItemData)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
     
    // Save the line number
    li.Line = value.Line

    return nil
}
```

You will notice that I created an inner struct and only decode the data to that struct. This is because if we were to call `Decode` on `li` itself, we would get a stack overflow, as decoding calls the `UnmarshalYAML` method repeatedly.

You can try this [online](https://goplay.space/#6Q38RRCwJxz) and see that the line numbers are set correctly.