# PyYAML customize loader to include depth level

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

I'm using PyYAML, and I'm trying to attach line numbers to dicts in my nested YAML structure, but only at the topmost level, e.g.:

```yaml
- id: 123
  __line: 1
  links:
    - name: "abc"
    # no line number here
    - name: "def"
```

There is [this answer that shows how to attach line numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53647080/2180570) by overriding `SafeLoader`, but this attaches the `__line` field to all dicts at any nesting level.

I ask in one of the comments there how to make this only apply to the top-most level of a structure, and @augurar gives an idea for a solution, but I need more help.

> Since the constructor performs a depth-first traversal, you could add an attribute to track current depth and override construct_object() to increment/decrement it appropriately. You'd need some extra logic to handle anchors correctly, if needed for your use case.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```py
class SafeLineLoader(SafeLoader):
    def construct_mapping(self, node, deep=True):
        mapping = super(SafeLineLoader, self).construct_mapping(node, deep=deep)
        if node.get("depth") == 0:
            mapping["line"] = node.start_mark.line + 1
        print(node)
        return mapping

    def construct_object(self, node, deep=False, depth=0):
        return super().construct_object(node, deep=deep, depth=depth + 1)
```

But I get the following error:

```bash
    return super().construct_object(node, deep=deep, depth=depth + 1)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: BaseConstructor.construct_object() got an unexpected keyword argument 'depth'
```

I guess because PyYAML's `construct_object` function is not expecting that `depth` argument. This may end up being a Python noob question about wrapping class methods and adding new arguments, or it may be that I just don't understand the architecture of this PyYAML library.

Comment: If you would upgrade to `ruamel.yaml`, you could just inspect the `.lc` attribute of the dict after loading. That is a `LineCol` instance which has a `line` and `col` attribute. So you do something like `data['some']['path'].lc.line` after loading into `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The depth information is not part of the original node attributes, nor is it propagated through the original calls, so you can't just call the original `construct_object` method with an additional `depth` argument.

Instead, notice that the [`compose_node`](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/957ae4d495cf8fcb5475c6c2f1bce801096b68a5/lib/yaml/composer.py#L63) method conveniently includes a `parent` argument, which is `None` for the root node, so you can override this method to add `parent` as an attribute to all nodes. Also note that all document nodes are sequence nodes themselves so a top-level mapping node always has a sequence node as a parent, so to check if a mapping node is a top-level one you can check if its parent node has a parent of `None`:

```
class SafeLineLoader(SafeLoader):
    def compose_node(self, parent, index):
        node = super().compose_node(parent, index)
        node.parent = parent
        return node

    def construct_mapping(self, node, deep=False):
        mapping = super().construct_mapping(node, deep=deep)
        if not node.parent.parent:
            mapping['__line__'] = node.start_mark.line + 1
        return mapping
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/ThankfulBluevioletHarddrive